# Sort a list of tuples according to the 2nd value of the tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Have a list of tuples. I want to sort according to the 2nd value of the tuples and return a tuple of two lists.

Here is the code:

```
def sort_artists(x):
    artist = []
    earnings = []
    z = (artist, earnings)
    for inner in x:
        artist.append(inner[0])
        earnings.append(inner[1])
    return z

artists = [("The Beatles", 270.8), ("Elvis Presley", 211.5), ("Michael Jackson", 183.9)]
print(sort_artists(artists))
```

Desired output is

```
(['Elvis Presley', 'Michael Jackson', 'The Beatles'], [270.8, 211.5, 183.9])
```

Output which i get is,

```
(['The Beatles', 'Elvis Presley', 'Michael Jackson'], [270.8, 211.5, 183.9])
```

Comment: You specifically call the function and print the output twice.  How do you think that this will give you the output only once?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the lists of tuples before turning them into a tuple of lists. Simply add `x.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)` as the first line in your function like below.

```
# your function
def sort_artists(x):
# sorts tuples by second value (x[1]), if reverse=True it will sort descending
    x.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)  
    artist = []
    earnings = []
    z = (artist, earnings)
    for inner in x:
        artist.append(inner[0])
        earnings.append(inner[1])
    return z

artists = [("The Beatles", 270.8), ("Elvis Presley", 211.5), ("Michael Jackson", 183.9)]

# call your function
list_artists = sort_artists(artists)

#print(list_artists)
'''
(['Michael Jackson', 'Elvis Presley', 'The Beatles'], [183.9, 211.5, 270.8])
'''
```

For more information, and other options, check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-second-item/).

Comment: The OP wants a function to do everything, it is not convenient to do it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the function will do the work. I changed the test values of your `artists` list to show that it works.

```
def sort_artists(x):
    artist = []
    earnings = []
    for inner in x:
        artist.append(inner[0])
        earnings.append(inner[1])
    index = sorted(range(len(earnings)), key=lambda k: earnings[k])
    artist = [artist[i] for i in index]
    earnings = [earnings[i] for i in index]
    z = (artist, earnings)
    return z

artists = [("The Beatles", 250), ("Elvis Presley", 530), ("Michael Jackson", 120)]
print(sort_artists(artists))
```

Output:

```
(['Michael Jackson', 'The Beatles', 'Elvis Presley'], [120, 250, 530])
```